# How is the below query evaluated by the complier?

Tags: sql

I was trying to create alternate queries to get the required result just came up with the below code. The below code gives Robert as the result i want to understand how is the compiler evaluated the below code.

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
    
    /* Create few records in this table */
    INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom');
    INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy');
    INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Frank');
    INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,'Jane');
    INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(5,'Robert');
    COMMIT;
    
    /* Display all the records from the table */
    SELECT * FROM NAMES a where 0 = (select count(Name) from NAMES b where b.Id > a.Id);
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: THe column `name` should be created as `NOT NULL` for it makes no sense for a name to be null in the table of names. `count(Name)` should be `count(*)` for the same reason; there must be no names that are null, so we don't have to check for null / not null (which is what `count(expression)` does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row in `names` it is checked whether the number of rows with a higher ID is 0. Only in that case is the row selected. This means only the row with the highest ID gets selected.

It is unnecessary to count, though. More typical would be a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM names name_with_higher_id
  WHERE name_with_higher_id.id > names.id
);
```

Or a `MAX` query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names
WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM names);
```

Comment: Thanks , Also for clarity can you write down the iterations for the above query if possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "iterations"?

Comment: okay let leave it i get the point , thanks for the quick reply.